# Label Venn diagram section with arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, venn-diagrams

I'd like to draw a curved arrow originating beneath the diagram and pointing to the center of the diagram, where the circles all converge. Where the arrow originates, I'd like to be able to make a label.

How do I do that?

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{venn circle/.style={draw,circle,minimum width=6cm,fill=#1,opacity=0.4}}

  \node [venn circle = red] (A) at (0,0) {$cognitive$};
  \node [venn circle = blue] (B) at (60:4cm) {$linguistics$};
  \node [venn circle = green] (C) at (0:4cm) {$childhood$};
  \node[left] at (barycentric cs:A=1/2,B=1/2 ) {}; 
  \node[below] at (barycentric cs:A=1/2,C=1/2 ) {};   
  \node[right] at (barycentric cs:B=1/2,C=1/2 ) {};   
  \node[below] at (barycentric cs:A=1/3,B=1/3,C=1/3 ){X};
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add some image mock-up of what you want or describe it in a bit more detail? Which direction should the curve bend, how much curvature, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Name the node that has the "X" text; since nodes are now named, you can use those names to add the arrow using a simple `\draw` operation; the `out`  and `in` keys to the `to` operation can give you the curved arrow (`bend` would be another option here) and using an extra `\node` you can add the label (as part of the `\node` text or using the `label` key). Here's an example, showing three possibilities (adjust the settings according to your needs):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{venn circle/.style={draw,circle,minimum width=6cm,fill=#1,opacity=0.4,text opacity=1}}

  \node [venn circle = red] (A) at (0,0) {$cognitive$};
  \node [venn circle = blue] (B) at (60:4cm) {$linguistics$};
  \node [venn circle = green] (C) at (0:4cm) {$childhood$};
  \node[left] at (barycentric cs:A=1/2,B=1/2 ) {}; 
  \node[below] at (barycentric cs:A=1/2,C=1/2 ) {};   
  \node[right] at (barycentric cs:B=1/2,C=1/2 ) {};   
  \node[below] at (barycentric cs:A=1/3,B=1/3,C=1/3 ) (endpoint) {X};
  \draw[->] 
    ([yshift=-20pt]A.south) node[anchor=east] {some text} 
    to[out=0,in=270] 
    (endpoint.south);
  \draw[->] 
    ( [yshift=-20pt] $ (A.south)!0.5!(C.south) $ ) node[anchor=north] {some other text}
    to[bend right,looseness=2] 
    (endpoint.south east);
  \node at ([yshift=-15pt]C.south) (textbelow) {yet another text};
  \draw[->] 
    (textbelow.north)
    to[out=90,in=0] 
    (endpoint.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I added `text opacity=1` to your style so the text is not transparent (this is optional).